# how to determine at which variable includes a user input

Tags: java, jlist

I'm creating a program in which will ask the user (for example) a student name then ask how many subjects do that student have, and then ask the subjects. But how can i know that those subjects are belong to that student ?

```
package test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class test2 {
private JTextField textField;
private JList nameList;
private DefaultListModel nameListModel;
private JList subjectList;
private DefaultListModel subjectListModel;
private JTextField textField_1;

public test2() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(51, 45, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(51, 100, 136, 118);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    nameListModel = new DefaultListModel(); 

    nameList = new JList(nameListModel);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(nameList);

    subjectListModel = new DefaultListModel();
    subjectList = new JList(subjectListModel);
    JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane_1.setBounds(228, 101, 136, 118);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane_1);
    scrollPane_1.setViewportView(subjectList);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {



        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(51, 278, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(135, 11, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblProfName = new JLabel("Prof. name : ");
    lblProfName.setBounds(49, 14, 76, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblProfName);






    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String data = textField.getText();
            nameListModel.addElement(data);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(data);

            textField.setText(null);

            int count = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter how many Subjects : ",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION)) ;


            String [] array = new String [count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                array[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Subject : ");
                subjectListModel.addElement(array[i]);

            }
        }
    });


}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    new test2();
}
}
```

the user can add many students as he/she wants, and subjects to that student. 
also, Im I doing it right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can store a StudentId as int value. Depending on that value you can afterwards extract the results.

..create a single new field,

```
private int studentId;
```

..once user has started editing, update this value. Since it is an int, you can call `studentId++` on it and it will keep updating untill the user has finished adding student.

Each studentId would be attached to the subject, or vice versa. It depends on what is being provided with a high priority, student or the subject.

While extraction, you can simply get the studentId and the subjects related to him and show them or what ever.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an embedded database with a table Students? You can retrieve the subjects of every Student whenever you want